# cvShowImage doesn't show the image

Tags: c++, opencv

Sometimes cvshowimage of openCV doesn't show the image, but shows a black empty one.

Does anyone know why and when this happens?

Comment: Provide some sample code that triggers your problem, otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: the code is as simple as cvShowImage(img).  nothing more complicated.

Answer (score 8):

```
cvShowImage(img);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

Make sure the second statement is there, otherwise the image will not be redrawn.

Also note that if your image is black and empty, then `cvShowImage` will show you a black and empty image.  That doesn't mean it is broken -- what's more likely is that there is a problem with the way you are loading/manipulating the image.  It's hard to say more without looking at your source code.

Answer (score 0):

to show image using opencv in vc++ below code is very simple an easy

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   IplImage* img =  cvLoadImage("d:\\gray.bmp"); 
         //show the  image
        cvNamedWindow("gray");
        cvShowImage("gray",img);
         cvWaitKey(0); //wait for a key press

        //cleaning up
        cvDestroyAllWindows(); 
        cvReleaseImage(&img);

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: dear, above code is using opencv's deprecated **C** api, not c++. you should not use it, and, in the interest of the opencv community, should not advise others to do so. also, please leave questions from 2011 alone, it's all horribly outdated.